# Connecting Lumia 535 on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10

I am currently using Ubuntu 14.10 & i want to connect my lumia 535 as MTP to transfer files,How do i do that?
Are any additional drivers required?

Answer (score 0):

I have copied from Lumia 520 topic, I changed few places and it worked on me!

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp 
sudo apt-get update
```

then;

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
```

add this to what did just opened;

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0421", ATTRS{idProduct}=="06fc", SYMLINK+="libmtp", MODE="0666", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1"
```

ctrl+o to save. ctrl+x to exit.

then paste this. mount device again :)

```
# udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Hope it works. (I know this answer was late sorry lol)